# Sharing Web.Config for multiple sites in solution

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Our project is currently setup with 2 websites, 1 class library inside a solution. Our class library is where we keep all the core components used be either site. It contains an App.Config but no Web.Config.

What I am trying to do is move one of the Web.Config (they're both the same) and move it into the class library and have both sites use a single Web.Config.

I have tried Google but perhaps do not know what to search for or this isn't possible? Can it be done, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just keep the config settings that are relevant to the class library contained within the app.config & override them in the web.config if they need to be different for a build configuration for your web app?

Comment: the biggest hurdle I am trying to overcome is both sites use the same data connection string, and I want to not have to maintain them separately. I'd rather have all the settings in the class library, and extend any site specify settings in their own web.config. 

someone mentioned that you can inherit/import configuration files?

Comment: I should mention, the data/repository layer is in the class library. both sites use the class library to access the database.

Comment: Personally, if it's two separate sites i'd always rely on distinct web.config files - how often are they likely to change? If you need something to transform them for different build configurations have a look at slow cheetah on nuget. This might be overkill for 2 sites but you might find it useful: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/301610-multiple-sites-sharing-single-web-config-file